# Подкиньте идею как создать весы на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть задание - создать весы,  на которые можно будет класть по обе стороны предметы, и если одна сторона перевешивает, то весы должны наклоняться. Суть вопроса в том, как реализовать систему наклона в одну сторону. То есть, чем больше перевес, тем больше угол. Макс ананас 1,5 кг. и мин 40 гр другого. Саму механику закидывания объекта на весы я вроде как придумал. Осталось придумать как измерять угол. Буду благодарен за идеи

Comment: в юнити есть физика (Unty - полагаю опечатка). Вам нужо расчитать силу, которая будет тянуть к земле (влияет вес с другой стороны весов; удаление палки от центра перевеса (относительно двух сторон), если это обычные весы;)

Comment: Возможно, что угол не придется изменять вообще (т е он сам измениться без расчетов, если сделать объекты весов твердыми). Нужно будет избежать только лишнего смещения.

Comment: Встроенный физический движок можно использовать, но гораздо проще и удобнее будет реализовать формулы в коде.

Comment: Вы бы хоть пояснили, что конкретно вы хотите получить, нужна ли вам досконально верная физика, нужна ли анимация движения рычага или вам достаточно конечное положение?